# HowTo use the pbsi font under xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex

Running `pdflatex`, the commands
`\usepackage{pbsi}` and `\bsifamily`
are sufficient to get parts of my text in BrushScriptX-Italic.

How can I achieve this when running `xelatex`?

The fonts are stored in:

```
.../fonts/vf/public/brushscr/pbsi8t.vf
.../fonts/map/dvips/brushscr/pbsi.map
.../fonts/tfm/public/brushscr/pbsi8t.tfm
.../fonts/tfm/public/brushscr/pbsi.tfm
.../fonts/tfm/public/brushscr/pbsi8r.tfm
```

the other stuff in:

```
.../latex/brushscr/t1pbsi.fd
.../latex/brushscr/pbsi.sty
```

I am on Xubuntu 22.04, last update with TeXLive 2022 last update.

My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pbsi}
\begin{document}
Dear Ulrike
\bsifamily
here is your test
\end{document}
```

Comment: always add a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: OK, added a MWE

Comment: In the package documentation, it was cleared mentioned that it will work on `T1` encoding only, so it works on either `LaTeX->dvips->PS2PDF` or `PDFLaTeX` only

Comment: How complicated is it (what steps are needed) to circumvent this restriction?

Comment: @Jack It is better to use the equivalent fonts (`OTF` or `TTF` format) instead of using the `Brush` font in `XeLaTeX`, that is much easy.

Comment: OK, which is the equivalent OTF/TTF of the Brush font?

Comment: you presumably(?) are looking for  the windows system font \windows\fonts\BRUSHSCI.TTF  whch you could load directly as `\setmainfont{BRUSHSCI.TTF}` with `fontspec`

Comment: xelatex reports "xdvipdfmx:fatal: Sorry, pfa format not supported; please convert the font to pfb, e.g., with t1binary.", so you would have to change the font (and then to adapt the map file).  lualatex can use it. I don't know an ttf or otf replacement, the font mentioned by @DavidCarlisle isn't on my windows.

Comment: @David: that was the decisive answer, thanks

Comment: @Ulrike: It was neither on my linux box. But I downloaded brush-script-mt.zip from https://www.dafontfree.net/brush-script-mt-italic/f116652.htm

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Davids comment, I downloaded `brush-script-mt.zip` from dafontfree.net/brush-script-mt-italic/f116652.htm

After unpacking I stored `BRUSHSCI.ttf` in `.../texmf-local/fonts/truetype/` and ran `mktexlsr`

Now the font can be found.
To use it in xelatex I added:

```
\ifpdftex
 \bsifamily
\else
 \setmonofont{BRUSHSCI.ttf}[Scale=1.44]
 \ttfamily
 \linespread{0.5}\selectfont
\fi
```

I had to scale the font, because its size didn't meet the size under `pdflatex`.

And as the linespacing was far to big, I had to make it smaller.

With these two "corrections" I got the same as when running `pdflatex`.

When this is not the right way (which I fear) please correct me.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the fontspec documentation, in particular section `6.2 Scale`. Maybe you could avoid using large font if you directly scale the font to whatever size you like

Comment: I have edit my answer accordingly.